# flex container, how to justify center, but left align when no space for margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some code which is display flex, it has 2 columns, and i want it to be center aligned when there is real estate, but when the browser shrinks and there is no space , i want it to be left aligned. the content in the right can go hidden, but the content in the left needs to stay visible

```css
.menuHeader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menuHeader">
  <div class="menuHeader2">
    <div class="menuHeaderList"><i class="icon icon-mapMarker"></i>
      <div class="label">xxxxxx</div>
      <div class="name">xxxxxx</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuHeaderNav">
      <li><a>Full List</a></li>
      <li class="is-selected"><a href="fmtg.html">AAA</a></li>
      <li><a>sss</a></li>
      <li><a>ddd</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">fff</li>
          <li><a href="#">ggg</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hhh</a></li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried bootstraps grid system? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: need better explanation of required results. What content on left what on right...frame your question properly. provide better code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

When width will be less than 500px column will be removed.

```css
.menuHeader {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.menuHeader > div{
 flex:1 0 50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .menuHeader {
  flex-direction:column;
     align-items: left;
 }
 .menuHeader div:nth-child(even){
  display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="menuHeader">
    <div>Home1</div>
    <div>Home2</div>
    <div>Content1</div>
    <div>Content2</div>
    <div>Head1</div>
    <div>Head2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer. so I just did an overflow:auto on .menuHeaderNav and that helped .menuHeader2 stay in view and not scroll out of view in the left